# Identifying rowspan and colspan: html table using beautiful soup

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am having an issue with the beautiful soup module and re module. I am trying to write a python script that automatically converts HTML code into latex code. To draw tables, I have to first read various table attributes in HTML code such as `rowspan` and `colspan`. 
Here is my table in HTML code:

```
<html>
<body>
   <table border = "1">
       <tr>
           <td>Name</td>
           <td colspan="2">Alice</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td>Type</td>
           <td colspan="2">Client</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td rowspan="3">Parameters</td>
           <td>Param1</td>
           <td>Value</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td>Param2</td>
           <td>Value</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td>Param3</td>
           <td>Value</td>
       </tr>
</html>
```

First I have to locate where `colspan` and `rowspan` appear. I wrote the following script to do that:

```
import re

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open('table.html')as file:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(file, 'lxml')


for table in soup.find_all("tr"):
    for item in table.find_all('td'):
        row = re.findall(r'rowspan="[0-255]"', str(item))
        col = re.findall(r'colspan="[0-255]"', str(item))
        print(row)
        print(col)
```

Output is:

```
[]
[]
[]
['colspan="2"']
[]
[]
[]
['colspan="2"']
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[Finished in 1.622s]
```

I am fine with `colspan`. But not ok with `rowspan`. In 13th line of my HTML code, I have `rowspan`.  Why it is not in my output? Please help.

Comment: I think it's much simpler to use the builtin [HTML Parser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html)

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do: are you looking to exclude `<rowspan>`s and `<colspan>`s where their numeric attribute value is >255?

Comment: @Jack Fleeting . No. I am trying to get the number attached with `rowspan` or `colspan` expression so that I can write an equivalent latex table. 0-255 range is because I assume the 'span number' won't be greater than 255. But I understood that it does not work that way from the answer (Thanks to @Abdul Niyas P M ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is with the regex.

```
rowspan="[0-255]"
```

Here 0-2 a single character in the range between 0 and 2 and 55 matches a single character in the list 5 (case sensitive). So this regex can only match

- `rowspan="0"`
- `rowspan="1"`
- `rowspan="2"`
- `rowspan="5"`

You can also use the `HTMLParser` module to parse the tag attributes.(It's part of standard library)

```
>>> from html.parser import HTMLParser
>>>
>>> class MyParser(HTMLParser):
...     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
...         self.results = []
...         super(MyParser, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
...     def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
...         if tag == "td":
...             for attr, value in attrs:
...                 if ("colspan" == attr) or ("rowspan" == attr):
...                     self.results.append("{}=\"{}\"".format(attr, value))
...
>>> parser = MyParser()
>>>
>>> parser.feed(
...     """
... <html>
... <body>
...    <table border = "1">
...        <tr>
...            <td>Name</td>
...            <td colspan="2">Alice</td>
...        </tr>
...        <tr>
...            <td>Type</td>
...            <td colspan="2">Client</td>
...        </tr>
...        <tr>
...            <td rowspan="3">Parameters</td>
...            <td>Param1</td>
...            <td>Value</td>
...        </tr>
...        <tr>
...            <td>Param2</td>
...            <td>Value</td>
...        </tr>
...        <tr>
...            <td>Param3</td>
...            <td>Value</td>
...        </tr>
... </html>
... """
... )
>>>
>>> print(parser.results)
['colspan="2"', 'colspan="2"', 'rowspan="3"']
```

Comment: I believe you could use the ```HTMLParser``` module. Though (apart from his regex bug) I find ACA's code more _readable and lucid_. A relative newcomer to Python that doesn't know much about Beautiful Soup could get the gist of what his code is doing. Yours involves an abstract connection between the call to ```parser.feed()``` and the ```handle_starttag()``` callback that assumes familiarity with HTMLParser. Not implying his is therefore clearly to be preferred; but I see that upside.